# Alternate way to download file from azure blob storage

Tags: python, azure, azure-blob-storage

I am trying to download files from azure blob storage and I want to download it without using any file handler or open or close method.

This is my approach I want an alternative approach without using "with open()"

`

```
def download_to_blob_storage(CONTAINERNAME ,remote_path,local_file_path):
    client = BlobServiceClient(STORAGEACCOUNTURL, credential=default_credential)
    blob_client = client.get_blob_client(container =CONTAINERNAME,blob = remote_path)

    with open(local_file_path, "wb") as my_blob:
       download_stream = blob_client.download_blob()
       my_blob.write(download_stream.readall()) 
    print('downloaded'+remote_path+'file')

download_to_blob_storage(CONTAINERNAME , '/results/wordcount.py',"./wordcount.py")
```

`

Comment: Are you using **Azure-devops**?

Answer (score 1):

For this question, first make sure what do you want to do.

What kind of concept is the "download" you want to achieve? If you just want to get the file content, I can provide you with a method. But if you want to avoid python's I/O mechanism to implement creating and writing files, **then this is not possible.** The open method of file is the most basic method of python's native, if you want a file that can be stored on disk, you will inevitably call this method.

A python demo for you:

```
from azure.storage.blob import BlobClient, ContainerClient


account_url = "https://xxx.blob.core.windows.net"
key = "xxx"
container_name = "test"
blob_name = "test.txt"
# Create the ContainerClient object
container_client = ContainerClient(account_url, container_name, credential=key)

# Create the BlobClient object
blob_client = BlobClient(account_url, container_name, blob_name, credential=key)

#download the file without using open
file_data = blob_client.download_blob().readall()

print("file content is: " + str(file_data))
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: Is it possible to do this with BlobServiceClient instead of blobclient?